# What's wrong with this createForm arguments?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm just starting with symfony forms, and i dont get it, why i get this type of errors:
[screen from profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8xqQ.png)

So what schould i pass as argument to make it properly work ?
Here's my code from RegisterController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="register")
 */
public function showRegisterAction()
{
    $registration = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(new Register(), $registration, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('create'), 'method' => 'POST']);

    return $this->render("/login/register.html.twig", ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

and my code of Register class with fromBuilder:

```
class Register extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', 'text', ['label' => 'USERNAME'])
        ->add('mail', 'email', ['label' => 'email'])
        ->add('password', 'password', ['label' => 'password'])
        ->add('password_repeat', 'password', ['mapped' => false, 'label' => 'confirm'])
        ->add('company', 'text', ['label' => 'company'])
        ->add('nip', 'text', ['label' => 'nip'])
        ->add('street', 'text', ['label' => 'street'])
        ->add('street_nr', 'text', ['label' => 'street_nr'])
        ->add('postal_code', 'text', ['label' => 'postal_code'])
        ->add('city', 'text', ['label' => 'city'])
        ->add('tel', 'text', ['label' => 'tel'])
        ->getForm();
}

public function getName()
{
    return "register";
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User']);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createForm` method expects the first argument to be the form class name (a string), not an instance of it.

So change this line:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new Register(), $registration, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('create'), 'method' => 'POST']);
```

to

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    Register::class,
    $registration,
    ['action' => $this->generateUrl('create'), 'method' => 'POST']
);
```

Also, note that you don't need the `getForm()` FormBuilder's method while creating form classes.

For reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Comment: Thanks for help :) !

Comment: You are welcome. Also, note that you don't need the `getForm()` FormBuilder's method while creating form classes.